# Is there a bug in artist radio?

Tags: deezer

When reloading

http://api.deezer.com/artist/6804523/radio/?index=7&limit=3 (while not logged in), the songs do not stay in order, and may not even be the same songs.

i.e. hitting the above URL returns different results each time.

Is this as intended?

Comment: It is intended yes, as a radio is somethingg that nevers stays on the same track.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Fred_Dzr, "a radio is somethingg[sic] that nevers[sic] stays on the same track"